# new promise inside a async function in order to grab the value outside of the async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I am returning a new Promis inside a async function that is doing a request to a api, I can console log the request from the api just fine inside the function. But when I try and resolve the same line I consoled `document.sold` it does not work. I expected the `checkPriceId` variable to return a promise which I could then catch with .then, but that does not seem to work. I have also tried using promise.all around the documents.forEach loop to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code

```
const checkPriceId = async test => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = `*[_type == "products" && price_id == "${body.price_id}"]`
        client.fetch(query, {}).then(documents => {
          documents.forEach(document => {
            //console.log(document.sold)
            resolve(document.sold)
          })
        })
      })
    }

    checkPriceId.then(test => {
      console.log(test) // does nothing
    })

    console.log(checkPriceId) // just returns a async function

    checkPriceId()
```

Comment: You need to call `checkPriceId`: `checkPriceId().then(...)`

Comment: you don't want to call ```resolve``` on each document btw, you probably want to call ```resolve``` with an array of ```documents.sold``` (idem ```resolve(documents.map(x => x.sold))```) but first you may follow @blex instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @blex mentinoned, you are not *calling* checkPriceId on line 13.

However, as also mentioned by @grodzi, you cannot `resolve` your promise multiple times. Once the `resolve` fn is called once (on line 7), subsequent calls will be ignored.

Since mixing Promises and async the way you are can be verbose and opaqueI'd suggest you just use async/awiat here. This will greatly help your code readability.

Here's a fixed example:

```
const checkPriceId = async (test) => {
  
  const query = `*[_type == "products" && price_id == "${body.price_id}"]`;

  const documents = await client.fetch(query, {}); // this could throw

  return documents.map(document => document.sold);
}

checkPriceId().then(test => {
  console.log(test) // this will log the return value from line 7
})
```

Answer (score 3):

[Why use the Promise constructor at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)? `client.fetch` already returns a promise, and you're also inside an async function which also returns a promise. Assuming all documents have a `.sold` that you're trying to get back in an array:

```
const checkPriceId = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "products" && price_id == "${body.price_id}"]`
  const documents = await client.fetch(query, {})
  return documents.map(({ sold }) => sold)
}

checkPriceId.then((soldList) => {
  console.log(soldList)
})
```

This also removes the `test` argument to `checkPriceId` since it wasn't being used.